# How to replace the content of every file in the directory?

Tags: powershell

There is a function (`Function($_)`) that replace all "1" with "2" for each file in the directory. New content is written to the file `out.txt`.

input: in.txt → 111

output: in.txt → 222 → out.txt

Tell me, please, how to make the replacement take place inside of every file?

```
Get-Content "C:\Dir\*" | ForEach-Object {Function($_)} > C:\Dir\out.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure I  understand what you mean, can you clarify what the new content is supposed to be? Also remember to choose a title that describes the problem rather than labels the tool used - that is done through the tags, which you already chose correctly. You can edit this question using the "edit" button.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content "C:\Dir\*"` will give you the content of everything in `C:\Dir` in one go, so you won't be able to modify each file individually. You'll also get errors for any directory in `C:\Dir`.

You need to iterate over each file in the directory and process them individually:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Dir' -File | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_.FullName
  (Get-Content $file) -replace '1','2' | Set-Content $file
}
```

The parentheses around `Get-Content` ensure that the file is read and closed again before further processing, otherwise writing to the (still open) file would fail.

Note that the parameter `-File` is only supported in PowerShell v3 or newer. On older versions you need to replace `Get-ChildItem -File` with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Dir' | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | ...
```